# raco executables linked to invalid runtime

Tags: macos, racket, homebrew, dynamic-linking, raco

I have Racket installed via homebrew. When I attempt to create an executable with raco, per:

```
raco exe my_prog.rkt
```

...the resulting binary is linked to a Racket runtime with an invalid path. This can be seen with `otool -L`:

```
my_prog:
    /usr/local/Cellar/racket/6.3/lib/racket/Racket.framework/Versions/6.3_3m/Racket (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
```

The correct path doesn't contain `racket/` after `lib/`. Thus, when you attempt to run the binary, `dyld` complains and aborts execution.

I can fix this, using `install_name_tool`:

```
chmod +w my_prog
install_name_tool -change /usr/local/Cellar/racket/6.3/lib/racket/Racket.framework/Versions/6.3_3m/Racket /usr/local/Cellar/racket/6.3/lib/Racket.framework/Versions/6.3_3m/Racket my_prog
```

...however, obviously this isn't something I want to have to do all the time!

Presumably raco is getting this invalid path from somewhere. Is there some way that I can configure this correctly?

Comment: FWIW the Homebrew script for Racket (version 6.3) is: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/17dd397c5d5ba04a3ce104d05d53a2ff17edfdef/Library/Formula/racket.rb

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but I recommend downloading Racket directly from here:  http://download.racket-lang.org/  (Note the latest version is 6.4)